# Export Talend items from talend studio put on SVN and build it from Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins, talend

Hi I am using talend open studio 5.5. I want to export talend job and put into the SVN. It contains the following files.
1) process
   a) .items
   b) .properties

I want to build talend job from this and create jar, bat and sh files as created when build job in talend open studion.

Comment: You can build the jar directly in the Studio and then use that however you want. Why do you specifically want Jenkins to build it?

Comment: For sharing the projects we need only export and put on svn which contains the above mentioned folder structure. Now to deploy we need to build the job in talend which can be then pushed to my svn and then pull from my execution server. I want any building tool to do this and deploy to the execution server. Or please let me know if we can automate this by writing some scripts.

Answer (score 4):

[This part](http://blog.nanthrax.net/?p=490) of a [series](http://blog.nanthrax.net/?p=434) explains how to use the Talend command line tool to build jobs from outside of the studio. It's scriptable so can be access from an external tool and in this case Jean-Baptiste uses Maven as a build tool.

His example `commandline-script.sh` inits the Talend repository, logs on as a user and then publishes an ESB route:

```sh
initRemote ${tac.location}
logonProject -pn ${talend.project} -ul "${tac.user}" -up ${tac.password}
publishRoute ${project.artifactId} -r "${repo.snapshot}" -u ${repo.user} -p ${repo.password} -pv ${project.version} -g ${project.groupId} -a ${project.artifactId}
```

He then uses a Maven POM to call this commandline script.

Typically you'd use Jenkins to build a Maven or Ant project as part of a continuous integration setup so these steps should be pretty easy for you to follow if you're using Maven as your build tool but the main premise is using the command line tool to build Talend jobs from an external script/application.

Jean-Baptiste is a [Talend employee](https://talend.com/members/jonofre) who specialises in ESB so this tutorial is aimed at ESB but, once again, the main point is that you can use the command line tool to externally build Talend job.

The official approach to this would of course be to buy an Enterprise licence that comes with a Talend Administration Centre. From here you can build jobs (it's providing a GUI hook into the command line to do so), deploy to any job execution server and execute on a combination of CRON, time based (eg. every 42 seconds for 10 iterations) or file based triggers.

The Enterprise licences also include an integrated SVN repository designed to better fit the vagaries of Talend projects.

Comment: Sadly the links in the first line of this don't work anymore.