# How to create a .WAR file from a Talend job by command

Tags: maven, jenkins, war, talend

I know it's possible to create .WAR-files using Talend Studio.
But we want to have a CI - environment (Jenkins) which will create the .WAR file after a change in the job is detected.

We can use a build-tool like Maven. 
But we have to execute the same commands as Talend Studio is performing implicit. So we can create the WAR manually.
Can someone tell us which steps/commands this are?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [cookbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883525/export-talend-items-from-talend-studio-put-on-svn-and-build-it-from-jenkins) (link to Jean Baptiste's blog from there for full details) on how to export a job from Talend Admin Center.

And here's [another quick guide](http://talendwithmahesh.blogspot.com/2015/03/talend-command-line.html) on options for the Talend CLI. To get a WAR, you'd use the extension .war on your file name. And you can see all options after logging on using 'help'